# Calling a Flow from Canvas app will not work for users after importing the solution to the PROD environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, powerapp, power-platform

We have the following:-

1. Solution created inside our Default environment.
2. Inside the Solution we have created a Canvas Power App.
3. The Power App contains a button which calls a Power Automate instant Flow using this formula:-

Set(varresult,'PowerApp->RespondtoaPowerApporflow'.Run().result)

4. now i shared the Power Apps with multiple users and they can call the flow by clicking on the button without any issues

Then

1. I export the solution from the Default environment as managed solution
2. I import the solution inside the PROD environment.
3. I re-share the imported Power App with the related users and i granted the users "Basic User" role inside the PROD environment.
4. but when the users click on the button inside the Power App on PROD environment, they will get this error "Connection bot configured or this service":-

[image]

While using my user name who is the owner of the app and who did the import and export i can call the flow on PROD without any issue

Now to fix this i did the following workaround:-

1. Inside the PROD environment >> I access the default Solution >> then i edited the Power App >> remove the Flow and re-add it >> Publish the App >> then all users were able to call the flow from the Power App.. but is this workaround acceptable? as i am editing a managed solution inside the PROD environment, which we should not do i am i correct? and is they another fix for this issue?

Thanks